# Creating A Faux Currency Chrome Extension

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, google-chrome-extension

Concept: So in an effort to learn more about web programming, I am trying to make a google chrome extension for my friends and myself which would display the amount of an imaginary currency we all have and the user would have the ability to give some to another user with the click of a button. There will only be 10 users including myself. There will be a button next to the omnibox which when clicked would open a popup (popup.html) that displays everyone's Name, Amount of Currency, and a '+' button which would subtract 1 unit from the user and add 1 unit to the person whose button was clicked. In order to identify the current user, when they first run the extension, it would prompt them for an ID number which I would provide for my friends personally.

Approach: I've found plenty of documentation on how to build basic chrome extensions, so that isn't much of an issue. Storing, manipulating, and displaying the currency is the part I have trouble with. My original idea was to just use WebSQL because chrome supposedly works well with it and I am proficient in Oracle SQL already. However it looks like WebSQL is an abandoned platform. 
My next approach was to use a MySQL database hosted on a server, and use php/ajax (which I am looking into learning) to pull the the info from the database, display it in the extension, and manipulate the data. However I have read that you can't use php with a chrome extension. But my thought was I could have the buttons `onclick` link to a php script with the arguments in the URL on the same server as the mysql databse. But I don't know if I could handle displaying the values the same way. Also I would store the User ID with `localstorage`.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible? Or at least point in the right direction? I am not begging to be spoonfed code, I just want to know which approach I need to take to tackle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do.  Here are my thoughts:

First, your chrome extension could use something like localStorage to store the unique identifier for the current user.  What I would do is make this part of the options part of the chrome extension.  If you make an options.html file, its not that hard to get that as part of the configuration options.

Second, you can start up a simple PHP and MySQL web service to handle these requests.  Because you're just doing this for a trial run, you could even do without a heavy authentication scheme on your 'web service' - just use a static token or something in your web request that is available in the chrome extension (Please note: I'm not advocating this as the solution going forward, just something to get you started).

The PHP and MySQL service layer would basically track user IDs, and the values.  You'd have to generate a little bit of code to make sure that there wasn't any MORE currency in rotation that was totally allowed.  Obviously don't let users share more if they don't have any, etc.

You can send AJAX requests with your chrome extension TO PHP - perhaps using a json request.  So, whoever told you you can't use PHP with chrome extension was "right", but meaning you can't program with PHP in the extension (it's just javascript) - however, you CAN use javascript in the chrome extension to request data from a PHP web service.

At any rate - not spoonfed, I don't think?  You may want to check out my github page for some chrome extensions - for examples on how to store options.  And, of course, if you have questions about writing the PHP web services, feel free to post - or send me a message!

Good luck - and super great news to hear that you've developed a project for yourself - just to learn even!

Comment: Wow, thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for! So the things I am going to begin reading up on will probably be chrome extension options, web services, tokens, and AJAX. This is a great starting point, thanks again, and I'd love to check out your gitHub if you don't mind sending me a link.

Comment: Certainly - check out https://github.com/aaronsaray to see both of my chrome extensions.  Glad it helped out. :)